# Meaning of ''move'' as intransitive verb

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Robots have motors and gearboxes which move and can  wear out."

I  think motors and gearboxes  can't go to other places. In this sentence, what is the meaning of ''move'' ?

Comment: It's partly [definition 4](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/move) here *- to be put in motion or to turn according to a prescribed motion. Used of machinery.* Or to give another context where something can "move" without *going* anywhere, consider a portrait photographer saying to his subject *Don't move!* when he's about to take the picture. He means *Keep still!* in the sense of *Don't turn your head or blink or open your mouth*, not *Stay where you are and don't go anywhere.*

Answer (score 2):

The word *'move'* has more definitions than to displace from one place to another. In your case, the following definition applies

> ***move*** (verb) 
>  
>    - to have a regular motion, as an implement or a machine; turn; revolve. 
>   [Ref. Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/move?s=t)

Motors and gearboxes are associated with a rotatory motion, hence they *move* in operation.

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps a poorly worded sentence. In this context, the motors and gearboxes do not move: what actually happens is that there are parts within the motor or gearbox that move.

The sentence should really be written

> Robots have motors and gearboxes which contain moving parts that can wear out."